# What is the default `SignificanceTest` setting for `FindClusters` with `Optimize` method?

Tags: implementation-details, cluster-analysis

According to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PartitioningDataIntoClusters.html), the default value of `FindCluster`'s `Method` option is `Optimize`.

Every value of this `Method` option, however, allows the specification of a further `SignificanceTest` *suboption*.

The documentation says that the two possible values for `SignificanceTest` are `Silhouette` and `Gap`, but I cannot find which of these is the default.

Does anyone happen to know what this default is?

(**NB:** the default `SignificanceTest` may very well depend on the method chosen, in which case I'm looking for the default `SignificanceTest` for the `Optimize` method.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out.  (I should have thought of this before.)

Basically, I clustered the data with all possible values of the `SignificanceTest` suboption, including the "no setting" case (i.e. the default), and compared the results.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it looks like the answer to my question is `Gap`.

---

FWIW, here's the code to generate `datapairs`, pretty much as given in the docs:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
GaussianRandomData[n_Integer, p_, sigma_] := 
  Table[p + {Re[#], Im[#]} &[
    RandomReal[
      NormalDistribution[0, 
       sigma]] E^(I RandomReal[{0, 2 \[Pi]}])], {n}];
datapairs = BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1234];
   Join[GaussianRandomData[100, {2, 1}, .3], 
    GaussianRandomData[100, {1, 1.5}, .2], 
    GaussianRandomData[100, {1, 1.1}, .4], 
    GaussianRandomData[100, {1.75, 1.75}, 0.1]]];
```